# could not load method in admin controller in nopcommerce 3.80

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce-3.80

I am creating new menu in admin panel and for called that menu I have created new controller named **AwazMaster** and in that I have created method named **Index**.

Now at run time when I click on that menu it shows me **page not found** in user side in nopcommerce 3.80.

I surprised why this type of message is showing me because I am getting correct url in browser link still showing the **page not found** message

And after that when I debug at the method and then run then I come to know that debug is not active in the method

Here is my code,

for add menu in admin panel

```
<siteMapNode SystemName="Master" nopResource="Admin.Master" PermissionNames="Master" 
controller="AwazMaster" action="Index" IconClass="fa-dot-circle-o" />
```

Here is the controller code,

```
using Nop.Services.Security;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Controllers;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Nop.Admin.Controllers
{
    public partial class AwazMasterController : BaseAdminController
    {
        #region Ctor

        public AwazMasterController()
        {            
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageCustomers))
                return AccessDeniedView();

            return View("../AwazMaster/Index");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Note : debug is not active in Index method when run project. It means could not load method when run the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, actually in nopcommerce 3.8 if we add any new controller then we want to build it that project because nopadmin and nopweb are both different project in 3.8 so we want to build it if we add controller in admin side.